# Scroll Table Horizontally Automatically to Left (using HTML, CSS or JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have following table, I want whole to scroll horizontally automatically, like marquee scroll to  right to left, without clicking any button. Is there any way to make scroll like marquee automatically using HTML, CSS or JQuery. Thank you.

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" id="table" style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2" id="mkdth">Pool Size (unheated pool)</th>
                <th rowspan="2" id="mkdth">Surface Area</th>
                <th id="with" colspan="2">WITHOUT POOL COVER</th>
                <th id="with" colspan="2">WITH POLCO POOL COVER</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="">Average Evaporation per Month (Feb-May)</td>
                <td>Average Evaporation per Day (Feb-May)</td>
                <td>Average Evaporation per Month (Feb-May)</td>
                <td>Average Evaporation per Day (Feb-May)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8.0*4.0m</td>
                <td>32.0m2</td>
                <td>6018 litres</td>
                <td>66 litres</td>
                <td>485 litres</td>
                <td>5.4 litres</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Scrolling to where? What destination point for scrolling?
Please be more specific.

Forward to this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: Give it a wider width then the page and set overflow-y: scroll, overflow-x: hidden. ?

Comment: @DutchPrime, overflow-x:hidden is disabling horizontal scrolling.

Comment: i am talking about scrolling automatically to the left.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Marquee CSS for this, use animations of CSS to create this effect

refer: https://htmleditor.w3schools.in/?filename=html_css_scrolling_text_using_css

mostly you need to work with (transform: translateX(100%);) this.

Comment: i want to scroll whole table

Comment: just go to the above link and in place of <p> tag, paste your <table> tag with the content and change the CSS from ( .marquee p ) to ( .marquee table )  and change the height in the ( .marquee ) CSS , You will get the desired effect.